# Would I need a gerund to make this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, independent-clauses

> I have lived my entire life in the United States, and to learn more
>   about the life my parents had lived as children was an incredible experience.

However, I then asked, "What was an incredible experience?" I realized that there is no noun to define what the experience was. Therefore, would I have to replace "to learn" with the gerund "learning"? Or is the sentence above completely fine? If it is already correct, why?

I feel as if the "to learn more about the life..." does not suffice as a subject for the latter independent clause in the sentence.

Comment: Either one is OK. But infinitives are less common as subjects than gerunds are; rules like Extraposition often move subject infinitives to the end of the sentence because English likes infinitives at the end.

Comment: "Our mission ***is*** to boldly go where no man has gone before." Clearly "to … go" functions as a noun.

Comment: @Scott Noun is **not** a function; it's a word category (part of speech). Functions are 'subject', 'object' complement' etc. In _Our mission is to boldly go ..._ , the sequence _to boldly go ..._ is an infinitival clause as predicative complement of "is". Nothing whatsoever to do with 'noun'.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence

> I have lived my entire life in the United States, and to learn more
>   about the life my parents had lived as children was an incredible
>   experience.

is fine. Replacing *to learn* with *learning* is OK too. *To learn* (an infinitive) and *learning* (a gerund) both work because both function as nouns.

An infinitive may function as a subject, direct object, subject complement, adjective, or adverb in a sentence. In the example you present, the infinitive functions as the subject of the second clause.

> to learn more about the life my parents had lived as children was an
>   incredible experience

may also be said as

> it was an incredible experience

(although in the context of your full sentence, "I have lived my entire life in the United States" would be seen as the antecedent to *it,* so you can't use *it* in the sentence as it is currently written; however, the point is that, taking  the second clause by itself, *it* could replace either *to learn ...* or *learning...*).

Comment: \ "I have lived my entire life in the United States, and so for me to learn more about the life my parents had lived as children was an inspiring experience."    I deeply dislike the wholesale use of the word "incredible," which is as much a cliché as "world peace" is to a beauty pageant contestant.

Comment: It's becoming more common every day. "Incredible" is, of course, one of Donald Trump's favorite adjectives.

Comment: \ You got that right! I wonder if his father tried to get a refund on Donald's college tuition money.